# Get color vector from histogram maxValue

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram

I'm trying to compute the most common color in an image. Using ***calcHist*** function, I understand I can get an histogram whose bins in a single channel are the pixel value, and the value of each bin is how many times is that value present in the image.

Also, it is easy to get the max value of the histogram (that is a double) and its position using ***minMaxLoc*** function.

But what I want is the whole color (the Vec3b object with the value of each channel).

Here's what I have so far:

```
 split(image, lab_channels); 

 histSize = 256;
 range[0] = 0;
 range[1] = 256;
 const float *lRange = {range};
 calcHist( &lab_channels[0], 1, 0, Mat(), 
     l_hist, 1, &histSize, &lRange, 
     true, false );

 histSize = 256;
 range[0] = 0;
 range[1] = 256;
 const float *aRange = {range};
 calcHist( &lab_channels[1], 1, 0, Mat(), 
     a_hist, 1, &histSize, &aRange, 
     true, 
     false );

 histSize = 256;
 range[0] = 0;
 range[1] = 256;

 const float *bRange = {range};
 calcHist( &lab_channels[2], 1, 0, Mat(), 
      b_hist, 1, &histSize, &bRange, t
      rue, false );

 minMaxLoc(l_hist, 0, 0, 0, &maxPos);
 result[0] = maxPos.y; 
 minMaxLoc(a_hist, 0, 0, 0, &maxPos);
 result[1] = maxPos.y; 
 minMaxLoc(b_hist, 0, 0, 0, &maxPos);
 result[2] = maxPos.y;
```

where **result** is my Vec3b vector with the most common color.

This code works fine (it does retrieve a color), but the problem is that it gets the most common color separately from each channel and finally it's not necessarely the most common color in the combined channels.

So, if I do this procedure, but for the 3 channels (like it's shown in opencv documentation), how can I get this Vec3b vector from the resulting histogram? or at least another data type I could cast or transform to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you can do:

1st) **Calculate the joint histogram**. use `calcHist` with the 3-channel image, instead of calculating one independent histogram for each channel.

2nd) look for the **maximum in the joint histogram**, just as you did with the channel histograms, using `minMaxLoc`.

Now, it would be wonderful if we knew what color is assigned to each bin in the joint histogram, but this is not straightforward. You can either look at the OpenCV implementation, or ask someone about it ..or try the following:

3rd) Set all the joint histogram values to 0, except the value corresponding to the maximum you just found. Set the value of this bin to the maximum value (i.e 1.0 if this is a normalized histogram). Then do a **backprojection** of the histogram to the original image (use [calcBackProject](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/back_projection/back_projection.html) for that). The pixels with the most-frequent color (the one you are looking for) should be highlighted in the backprojection image.

Hope that it helps!

Comment: So, for what I understood from your answer and the documentation, executing calcBackProject will get the pixels locations whose value is likely to be the most common one (could have some variations). Correct me if I'm wrong. I only have one last question: how are the matched pixels highlighted in the returning Mat object of this function? by their value? lets say they're all one's.

Comment: If your fixed histogram is all zeros except in the bin corresponding to the selected color, then the backprojection image would contain **non zero** values only in the pixels with such color value in the original image. This is, you can search for pixels with value >0 in the returned `Mat` object (or even use this `Mat` as a mask).